# Default Database From SQL Script in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, schema

Is it possible to get a table with a sql script from a specific schema, so I don't have to double click the schema in order to make it like the default/currently active schema in mysql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easily achieved by simply specifying the schema name as part of your SQL statement.

For example, if your schema is named `foobar` and your table is named `myTable`:

```
SELECT  *
  FROM  `foobar`.`myTable`;
```

The syntax for this is simply:

```
-- With backticks
`schema_name`.`table_name`

-- Without backticks
schema_name.table_name
```